# Border Height on CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table TD and on the right of it I want to add a 1 pixel border, so I've done this:

```
table td {
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

It works fine but the problem is that the border's height takes the total TD's height.

Is there a way to set the height of the border?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, there isn't. The border will always be as tall as the element.

You can achieve the same effect by wrapping the contents of the cell in a `<span>`, and applying height/border styles to that. Or by drawing a short vertical line in an 1 pixel wide PNG which is the correct height, and applying it as a background to the cell:

```
background:url(line.png) bottom right no-repeat;
```

Comment: Wow, Brilliant. Nice solution

Comment: For my issue, your first line answered my question.  "The border will always be as tall as the element."

Answer (score 130):

I have another possibility. This is of course a "newer" technique, but for my projects works sufficient.

It only works if you need one or two borders. I've never done it with 4 borders... and to be honest, I don't know the answer for that yet.

```css
.your-item {
  position: relative;
}

.your-item:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%; //You can change this if you want smaller/bigger borders
  width: 1px;
  
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; // If you want to set a smaller height and center it, change this value
  
  background-color: #000000; // The color of your border
}
```

Comment: THIS IS GREAT.  To set it `vertically centered`, we added `{top: 30%; height:40%}` >> the `total` should sum up to `100%` (`top:30%` will imply `bottom:30%` because `height:40%`).  Also setting `em` instead of `px` helps. GOod Luck...

Comment: This should the selected answer, it's the cleanest work around. I tryed in on a bootstrap col containing text but I forgot to set the position to absolute (that's why I'm here). Thank you.

Comment: I found this answer best for me

Answer (score 62):

Yes, you can set the line height after defining the border like this:

```
border-right: 1px solid;
line-height: 10px;
```

Comment: Just to add, the border doesn't have to be dotted, this works perfectly! Just how you would expect "border-height" (if it existed) to work.

Answer (score 8):

For td elements line-height will successfully allow you to resize the border-height as SPrince mentioned.

For other elements such as list items, you can control the border height with line-height and the height of the actual element with margin-top and margin-bottom.

Here is a working example of both:
http://jsfiddle.net/byronj/gLcqu6mg/

An example with list items:

```
li { 
    list-style: none; 
    padding: 0 10px; 
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #000; 
    line-height: 5px; 
    margin: 20px 0; 
}

<ul>
    <li>cats</li>
    <li>dogs</li>
    <li>birds</li>
    <li>swine!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Building on top of @ReBa's answer above, this `custom-border` class is what worked for me.

Mods:

- working with `border` **instead of** `backaground-color` since `background-color` is not consistent.
- Setting `height` & `top` of the properties of `:after` in such a way that the total comes up to `100%` where `bottom`'s value is *implicit*.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-border {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-border:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px #6c757d solid;
  top: 35%;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="custom-border">
    Hello
  </li>
  <li class="custom-border">
    World
  </li>
  <li class="custom-border">
    Foo
  </li>
  <li class="custom-border">Bar</li>
  <li class="custom-border">Baz</li>
</ul>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 7):

This will add a centered border to the left of the cell that is 80% the height of the cell. You can reference the full [border-image documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) here.

```
table td {
    border-image: linear-gradient(transparent 10%, blue 10% 90%, transparent 90%) 0 0 0 1 / 3px;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for this suggestion! 

Comment: I just tried it on a bootstrap col, didn't work :/

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me....!! 
We can change the place of the border by changing the "0 0 0 1" part in the above css.

For instance: if you need it on the right hand side "0 1 0 0"

```
borderImage: 'linear-gradient(transparent 10%, grey 10% 90%, transparent 90%) 0 1 0 0 / 1.5px '
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot set the border height.

Answer (score 4):

Just like everyone else said, you can't control border height. 
But there are workarounds, here's what I do:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}

table::before { /* ::after works too */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* Change direction for a different side*/
  z-index: 100; 
  width: 3px; /* Thickness */
  height: 10px;
  background: #555; /* Color */
}
```

You can set `height` to `inherit` for the height of the table or `calc(inherit - 2px)` for a 2px smaller border.
Remember, `inherit` has no effect when the table height isn't set.

Use `height: 50%` for half a border.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonSands/v47hnbf5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
table {
 border-spacing: 10px 0px;
}

.rightborder {
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Then with your code you can:

```
<td class="rightborder">whatever</td>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-box{  
    border: solid 10px;
}
.sub-box{
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

//draws a line on right side of the box.
later add a margin-top and margin-bottom.
i.e.,

```
.sub-box{
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This might help in drawing a line on the right-side of the box with a gap on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no, not without resorting to trickery. borders on elements are supposed to run the entire length of whatever side of the element box they apply to.

Answer (score -1):

```
table td {
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Just you add height under the border property.

Comment: that happened by default.