# Is there a way to set border line height?

Tags: html, css, border

You can control the width of a border using the border-right-width property. Is there a way to set the height of it like a border-right-height?

For example:

Home|About

But I want the | to be a little shorter.

Comment: There are only two dimensions of a border. Length and Width. Without seeing your code, I am not sure how better to direct you.

Comment: reffer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664057/border-height-on-css

Comment: No, you cannot tell the border to be smaller than the element, she goes around the element, using it's full height in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set the `border` property as you desire. However, using a pseudo element may be useful here ([see exaggerated live example](http://jsfiddle.net/zd7j8/5/)):

**HTML (possible--other configurations are possible also)**

```
<div class="menu"><span>Home</span><span>About</span><span>Last</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu span {font-size: 2em; padding: 10px; position: relative;}

.menu span:after {content: ''; position: absolute; right: 0; top: .6em; bottom: .6em; width: 1px; background-color: black;}

.menu > span:last-child:after {display: none;}
```

Comment: Given the number of sites on which I see people do why not just add it to the css standard?

Answer (score 0):

That would be connected to the height of the element itself - not the border.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method to set anything other than the width, style, and color of a border. If you want to make a border appear to be a different height than the text you need to add an element between those two elements and adjust its height and vertical alignment that way. You might be best off with a background image depending on what code you're working with.