# How to set table border less then cell height

Tags: css, html, html-table

I want that the divider border between the table cells will be half of it's height

see preview pic:[image]

Here is the fiddle link:

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s1om1fd2/embedded/result/)

```
#details_gdr {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0E0EA;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr th:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #D0E0EA;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr th {
    width: 28px;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664057/border-height-on-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is your solution.

```
#details_gdr {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0E0EA;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr:not(:last-child) th + th::before {
    color: #D0E0EA;
    content: '|';
    font-size: 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    left: -7px;
}

#details_gdr tbody tr th {
    width: 28px;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4ynsxt3/

Comment: Great answer Thank you!

Comment: This is very clever! Never occurs to me to use `|`... Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score -2):

you can use image at right side to be your divider like the following css:

```
background:url(line.png) bottom right no-repeat;
```